# Apache 2.4 Convert .htaccess and rewrite it to vhost.conf

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am rewriting the Apache 2.4 configuration that I've received from the old development team.

I have ~200 lines of similar configuration, and I can not understand on what principle I need to change this code to move it from `.htaccess` to virtualhost.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/application-module/(.*)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)json$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !playground/local-loader/(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1/ [R,L,NC]
```

When I just move it to the virtualhost my site crashes in places I don't understand.

Comment: In .htaccess, rewrite rules applies to the directory where .htaccess is located. In virtualhost, you must set these rules in a <Directory> or <Location> block.

Comment: Thanks!
I tried to do it this way, but it looks like the rules need to be changed somehow. I also understand that the file paths need to be fixed, but regular expressions drive me crazy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends where in the `<VirtualHost>` container you are placing these directives.

If you are using a `<Directory>` container (ie. a *directory* context) and *disabling* `.htaccess` overrides altogether (otherwise `.htaccess` will override the `<Directory>` container!) then you can pretty much copy the directives as-is (assuming the `<Directory>` container references the same directory as the `.htaccess` file did).

However, if you are putting these directives directly inside the `<VirtualHost>` container (outside of a `<Directory>` container), ie. in a *virtualhost* context, then you need to make some changes. This is because the directives are processed earlier, before the request is mapped to the filesystem.

In the directives you've posted, only two changes would be required:

- In a *virtualhost* context, the `REQUEST_FILENAME` server variable has not yet been resolved to a *filename*. It is the same as `REQUEST_URI` (ie. the URL that is requested). So, your filesystem check will always fail and the condition will always be successful! You either need to use a lookahead. eg. `%{LA-U:REQUEST_FILENAME}`, or construct the absolute filename yourself. eg. `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}`. For example:

  ```
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
  ```
- In a *virtualhost* context, the URL-path that is matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern* is root-relative (starting with a slash). Whereas in `.htaccess` it is relative to the directory that contains the `.htaccess` file - less the slash prefix. So, the rule as written would result in a double slash at the start of the URL-path, it should be rewritten like this instead:

  ```
  RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /$1/ [R,L]
  ```

  (The `NC` flag is not required here.)

  Or (preferable) don't use a backreference here and use the `REQUEST_URI` server variable instead (which would naturally work in `.htaccess` as well). For example:

  ```
  RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R,L]
  ```

  (*Aside:* This should probably also be a 301 permanent redirect (ie. `R=301`). As it stands, this will default to a 302 temporary redirect. But only change to a 301 - if that is the intention - once you have confirmed that it works as intended.)

#### So, in summary, this would become:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/application-module/(.*)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)json$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !playground/local-loader/(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /$1/ [R,L]
```

---

*Aside:*

The above can be immediately optimised a bit by moving the filesystem check (which is relatively *expensive*) to the last condition and moving the *condition* that checks that the request does not already end in a slash to the `RewriteRule` directive. Also, the regex subpatterns `(.*)` in each of the *conditions* are not required. So, the above could be rewritten more efficiently:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/application-module/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !json$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !playground/local-loader/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteRule !/$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R,L]
```

The filesystem check can perhaps be removed altogether if instead you exclude requests that contain (what looks like) a file extension, but this can depend on your file structure.

The *condition* that checks `!json$` looks like it should really be checking for the `.json` file extension, ie. `!\.json$`. (This ties in with my comment above about excluding *all* requests that have a "file extension".)

The first *condition* that checks that the query string is empty seems a little odd (since it doesn't really matter whether there is a query string or not when appending a slash to the URL-path), but I assume this must be a specific requirement?

Comment: this is awesome! everything make sense, and now it all works! Thank you many times!